# Is there a standard for math terminology?

Tags: terminology

I searched for the definition of "quotient" and I felt there were many answers. Is there a place that defines math terms? Something like a standard?

Comment: I'm afraid the answer is: no, there is no such standard.

Comment: There are quite a few things associated with the word quotient: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_(disambiguation)

Comment: You can see [ISO 31-11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_31-11#Sets) : "about mathematical signs and symbols, their meanings, verbal equivalents and applications".

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no canonical dictionary of mathematical terminology nor should there be.

The important thing is *context*. For example, to the average person quotient means something like $\frac{a}{b}$. To an algebraist there are things called quotient groups.

Mathematical terminology is always changing. A "number" a few thousand years ago might have only meant $1,2,3,...$ where now we have much broader ideas about what constitutes a number.

To answer your question more practically, just use textbooks or Wikipedia.